# Why do we need the random number in Pinochioo protocol compared with GGPR

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, snarks

I find it hard to fully grasp the whole [Pinocchio protocol](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/279.pdf)
.

I understand that the $\alpha$ s are for restricting the prover to compute only the corresponding set-up values.

But it's not clear for me to pick up $\gamma$ for the consistent(same) witness check.

From what I can tell, this protocol cleverly embedded different $r_v,r_w,r_y$ s to generators, $g_v,g_w,g_y$. An insightful improvement on [GGPR](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/215.pdf). By generating generators in this way, different $r$ s have already been encoded into the equation. All we need is another random number, $\beta$  to mitigate the malleability problem mentioned in this manual script [zksnark explain](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.07221).

So, why do we need another randomness $\theta$ in Pinocchio protocol? (Compared with the GGPR protocol)